# Building an authentication layer in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication

coming from over a decade of web application where cookie/session are the only form of auth-technology, I wonder what I could use to build, if it does not already exists, a re-usable authentication layer for an iOS application. 
Something that I could plug and switch on/off for my next built applications.

I am not talking about a strict security mechanism, but at least a module which could allow to have different users, where they can play with the application and apply local changes to it. At application start up, user would be prompted to enter user and password, then trough all the application lifecycle the user is 'remembered', and then forgotten at app shutdown.

The module could perform several authentication. The simplest mechanism I would like to start with is user and password stored into app, but I would like to extend in the future by adding authentication trough a central server, or a web service, or whatever is possible with it.

thanks

Comment: Get to know your options: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/SecuritySvcs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002650-SW1

Comment: thanks this is what I needed, write this as an answer, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mac OS X and iOS Secure Coding Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/SecuritySvcs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002650-SW1)